# Why does display:inline-block inside a table cell changes vertical alignment of following cells

Tags: html, css

Check out this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cu4u5xo5/2/

```
    .tbl {
        display: table;
        width:"100%";
    }
    .trow {
        display:table-row;
    }
    .ul {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .col {
        display:table-cell;
    }
    .col1 {
        background:#77c;
    }
    .col2 {
        background: #faa;
    }
    .col3 {
        background: #afa;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    .inside {
        display:inline-block;
        /* change this to block */
    }
```

```html
<div class="tbl">
        <div class="trow">
            <div class="col1">
                <div class="inside">
                    <ul>
                        <li>INSIDE ONE</li>
                        <li>INSIDE ONE</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col2">COLUMN TWO</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Divs have display table, table-row and table-cell.

When I set .inside to display:inline-block, following cells behave as if vertical-align:bottom. I can overwrite it by setting vertical-align:top, but I'm just wondering **why placing a div with inline-block in one cell changes a property of another cell?**

Comment: why don't you use a `<table>` for this? and inline block makes a div be inline with text so it might mess with other things inside that parent div.

Comment: In the project I'm working on it's not semantically a table, I'm just using it to position stuff the way I need to. I think I've read somewhere that you should use <table> only if it's actually a table with data.

Comment: yeah you should only use table if it is actually a table. but if you say things like `display: table` it is just the same as a table as for behaviour

Comment: Use tables if it makes sense, not because of someone says. Semantics, phhh!..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [CSS specifications](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align) (my emphasis):

> The vertical-align property affects the vertical positioning inside a line box of the boxes
>   generated by an ***inline-level*** element.

If you style the contents of the first cell as `block`, then it is no longer an inline element. As a result, the `vertical-align` property will have no effect, and the contents of the second cell will end up in their default position (aligned to the top of the cell).

Comment: but they actually end up at the bottom of the cell

Comment: @kihu Perhaps your default browser settings are different. In Google Chrome, when the unordered list wrapper is styled as a block-level element, the contents of the second cell are aligned to the top of the cell. This is the default position, because `vertical-align` has no meaning for a block-level element. When the wrapper is styled as an `inline-block`, then the second cell **does** have something to align itself to. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cu4u5xo5/11/) shows the same effect in an ordinary `<p>` element.

Comment: On my computer both Chrome and Firefox display COLUMN TWO vertically aligned to bottom. Also, without <ul> the same thing happens: http://jsfiddle.net/m0vskgp4/2/

Comment: Oh, I understand why <ul> doesn't matter here:) Still, why bottom?

Comment: @kihu Because ([according to W3Schools, at least](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp)) the default value of `vertical-align` is `baseline`.

Comment: Now I get it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try it [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cu4u5xo5/7/)

```
.inside {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: in the question he tells that he knows this works but its not what he means

Comment: otherwise , use the display: table-cell;

Comment: The link you provided doesn't explain this behavior